# C++ is marking a function as static once enough?

Tags: c++, static

If you have a definition of a function in the beginning of a .cpp file, and implement after the main function, using static in just one of them suffices its purpose?

```
#include <iostream>

static void foo(); //define func

int main()
{
foo();
return 0;
}

void foo() //do we need static here again or we can omit it?
{
//implementations
}
```

Comment: @AndyG I deleted my comment the moment I saw the post. Great timing on the reply btw! haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[basic.link]/3

> A name having namespace scope (6.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of ... a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared `static`

[over.dcl]/1

> Two function declarations of the same name refer to the same function if they are in the same scope and
>   have equivalent parameter declarations (16.1).  ...

Putting these together, the second declaration of `foo` simply redeclares the function that has already been declared previously, and that function has already been given internal linkage. So the two declarations declare the same function, and that function has internal linkage (is "static").

Comment: so I can use static on either one of them and the compiling is the same?

Comment: @philips_dvd no, it's illegal if you declare the second one static without declaring the first one static.

Comment: but why doesn't my compiler throw errors or warnings and compiles normally using static on just the second one?

Comment: @philips_dvd I don't know, but the standard explicitly calls this out as illegal. See the second example here: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#6

Comment: @philips_dvd You'll also find decent compilers reject having static only on the second one: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48912e7d2f758277  The problem's basically that the first declaration in the code in your question is implicitly `extern`, so there's a conflict if it sees an explicit `static` later; if it sees an *explicit* `static` first it is prepared to consider the second version implicitly static too though, so no error.  It's all a bit arbitrary but that kind of "feels" right: if you read a header top to bottom you shouldn't get a surprise, but have to remember it's `static`.

Comment: @philips_dvd it compiles because you are simply declaring _another_ function with the same name that is static (and unrelated to the first one).

Comment: @Aganju No. It is not supposed to compile. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f87535cedacffbc